# Problem with Clipshape and RoundedRectangle

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swiftui

I'm running into an issue where my ClipShape is disabled when a subview is bigger than the total screen width. I tried to patch it but i don't understand what's the problem here.

Here is two images and you'll found the code below :

[image: Whit one card. Card width is equal to UIScreen.main.bounds.width]
[image: With 3 cards.]

Here's my complete code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingView: View {

    @State var x: CGFloat = 0
    @State var count : CGFloat = 0
    @State var screen = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30
    @State var op : CGFloat = 0

    @State var data = [
        Card(id: 0, title: "Carte 1", image: "onboarding"),
        Card(id: 1, title: "Carte 2", image: "onboarding"),
        Card(id: 2, title: "Carte 3", image: "onboarding")
    ]

    var body: some View {

        ZStack(alignment: .top) {

            Color.black
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Color("background2")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))


            HStack(spacing: 15) {

                ForEach(data) { i in
                    CardView(data: i)
                        .offset(x: self.x)
                    .highPriorityGesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                if value.translation.width > 0 {
                                    self.x = value.location.x
                                } else {
                                    self.x = value.location.x - self.screen
                                }
                            }
                    )
                }
            }


//                CardView(data: data[0])

            }


        }
    }

struct OnboardingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnboardingView()
    }
}


struct CardView: View {

    @State var show = false
    var data: Card


    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            // Title - use the geometry reader to adapt font size.
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Text(self.data.title)
                    .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width / 9, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)

            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 375, maxHeight:  220)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)

            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        .offset(x: show ? 0 : -500)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding(.top, 25)
        .frame(height: 477)
        .background(
            ZStack {
                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Blob"))
                    .offset(x: -150, y: -200)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: show ? 360 + 90 : 90))
                    .blendMode(.plusDarker)
                    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 120).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                    .onAppear {
                        self.show = true
                }

                .background(
                    Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Blob"))
                        .offset(x: -200, y: -250)
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: show ? 360 : 0), anchor: .leading)
                        .blendMode(.overlay)
                        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 100).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                )
            }
        )
            .background(
                Image(self.data.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .opacity(0.8),
                alignment: .bottom
            )
            .background(Color("card1"))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
    }
}

struct Card: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var image: String
}
```

Can someone help please ?
The RoundedRectangle Clipshape only disapear when i display all my cards.
I think there's a problem because the total width of the HStack is larger than the background i applied the clipshape to.

How can i fix this ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that gives desired clipping

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {

        Color.black
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

        Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))

        Color.clear       // transparent clipped foreground window
            .background(
                VStack {  // clipped background content
                    HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        ForEach(data) { i in
                            CardView(data: i)
                                .offset(x: self.x)
                                .highPriorityGesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            if value.translation.width > 0 {
                                                self.x = value.location.x
                                            } else {
                                                self.x = value.location.x - self.screen
                                            }
                                    }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            )
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Asperi. Can you explain a little bit what was the problem ? And why did you found this solution. 

Will help a lot.

Comment: @theovogg, any stack container is tighten to internal content, in your case the HStack expands parent ZStack to its width, so round corners are just shifter out of screen. In proposed solution the geometry of parent ZStack is not changed, because background of view lives in view coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for XCode 15, iOS 16+

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
        Color.black.opacity(0.3)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
        
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
            // ...
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.white,
                    in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20,
                                         style: .continuous))
    }
}
```