# Swiftui Custom RoundedRectangle and Overlay Problem

Tags: swift, swiftui

I notice when i use an overlay on a rounded rectangle that there are some parts that are not overlayed, or maybe i'm doing it wrong

[image]
and then i tried to switch the view to a regular Iphone SE display, and i notice something that i really dislike, the top is not convered by red

Is there a way to fix it?? or any keyword for me to search? cuz there's probably someone with the same question as i am

Thanks

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:25)
                    .frame(height: 350, alignment:.center)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Kolor1"))
                    .overlay(
                        ZStack {
                            Text("Makan")
                            HStack {
                                Spacer().frame(width:80)
                                VStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image("Labtek")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .frame(width: 360, height: 260, alignment:.center)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

Comment: I see no issue in SwiftUI codes and result, it should be like that. you just expected wrong result.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701079/12299030? Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774757/12299030? Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62040898/12299030?